# what is the conjugate momentum for this variable?

Tags: symplectic-geometry, canonical-transformation

I am trying to find a canonical transformation for this Hamiltonian:
\begin{equation}
H(q,p) = p + e^p\cos(q)
\end{equation}
and I'm trying to find a conjugate momentum $P$ to the variable $Q$ defined by
\begin{equation}
Q(q,p) = e^p\cos(q) 
\end{equation}
I cannot solve the partial differential equations arising from the Poisson brackets, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\{Q(q,p), P(q,p)\} = 1 
\end{equation}

...anyone who can give me a hint on this?